# Using zcat in windows

Tags: xml, windows, unix, zcat

I have a big XML file which was splited in unix.
I got a readme file saying:

```
zcat FILE.xml.part1.gz File.xml.part2.gz > File.xml
```

should connect them into one parsable XML file.
The separation is guaranteed to be on a byte boundary, but not an XML stanza boundary.

I work on win7 and need to connect this 2 parts....
I tried WinZip and WinRar and both where unable to handle it (obviously).

How can i do that?

Thanks upfront.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got the minwg or cygnus environment installed, you could run `cat FILE.xml.part1.gz File.xml.part2.gz > File.xml.gz`, and then run that file through WinZip or WinRAR.

I think I've heard of the `hjsplit` tool for Windows to split and re-assemble split files. You could use `hjsplit`, if I'm correct on the tool :), to join the gzipped files and then uncompress the combined file.

Answer (score 2):

Unzip the file separately, using 7zip, and paste the results into an editor of your choice.

Comment: The files are 6G each opening them in editor will choke my pc